# C++ 11/14 doing a different operation in a single function based on template type

Tags: c++, templates

So i've got a bunch of shared_ptr's as private members of a class called 'Handler' each pointing to a different template Cache classes. Like so:

```
shared_ptr< Cache<T1> > t1Cache;
shared_ptr< Cache<T2> > t2Cache;
shared_ptr< Cache<T3> > t3Cache;
```

Each Cache class simply holds a map with a string as a key and T as the item and functions to get/update and add an item to the map. I want to have a single member function in 'Handler' for an update,add and get operations. So I could call for example: ( Where ITEM_TYPE is an enum )

```
Handler handler;
auto something = handler.getItem( key1, TYPE_T1 );
handler.addItem( key2, TYPE_T2, newItem );
handler.updateItem( key3, TYPE_T3, newValue);
```

I tried at first just having a switch based on the enum like so:

```
template <typename T>
auto addItem( const std::string& key, ITEM_TYPE type, T nItem )
{
    switch( type )
    {
    case TYPE_T1:
       t1Cache->addItem( key, nItem );
    break;
    case TYPE_T2:
       t2Cache->addItem( key ,nItem );
    break;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I have a basic knowledge of templates so I didn't realize that that will not work. At the moment as a temporary solution im just using a different function for each type, though i'd really like to consolidate it all into one. I thought that maybe 'constexpr if' will help but it's not supported, is this even possible?

EDIT: Sorry the title isn't really worded right, was not sure how to title this

Comment: What is `ITEM_TYPE`? It sounds like an enum or an int. You need **types** not values to make templating work. Hard to wrap your head around at first.

Comment: It's still not clear what your functions are meant to do, makes it hard to answer the question. You may also want to describe what your trying to accomplish, it isn't clear templates are a good fit here.

Comment: Do these different functions look/behave any different from one another? What does your `Cache` class look like?

Comment: The Cache class has an unordered_map< std::string, T> member and a bunch of functions that add, get and update an item in the map. What I want is a class that holds a bunch of caches and uses an enum to identify to which cache I want to add/update/get an item from.

Comment: Are `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` distinct? That is, will the types that the Caches are templated on never be the same as each other?

Comment: @Xsy: Then no, you cannot use an enum to determine which function to call. (unless the enum **value** is known at compile-time). Templates are compile-time things, and an enum value may change at run-time.

Comment: @AndyG They are distinct yes, never the same. Edit: Is there a way to do the same without enums then? The return type or type of what I want to add/update should be known at compile time.

Comment: If I understand right, you simply have two keys instead of one. You may use a map of maps for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

template <class T> class Cache
{
public:
  void addItem(std::string const& key, T item)
  {
  }
};

template <class... T> class SuperCache
{
public:
  template <class U> void addItem(std::string const& key, U&& item)
  {
    std::get<Cache<std::decay_t<U>>>(caches_).addItem(key, std::forward<U>(item));
  }

private:
  std::tuple<Cache<T>...> caches_;
};

int main()
{
  SuperCache<int, double> cache;
  cache.addItem("a", 5);
  cache.addItem("b", 5.0);
}
```

If you can use C++17, then here's another approach that might work (depending on your needs):

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <variant>

template <class... T> class VariantCache
{
public:
  template <class U> void addItem(std::string const& key, U&& item)
  {
    items_[key] = std::forward<U>(item);
  }

 private:
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::variant<T...>> items_;
};

int main()
{
  VariantCache<int, double> cache;
  cache.addItem("a", 5);
  cache.addItem("b", 5.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to do this but you could encapsulate all caches into a tuple and use `get<T>` within your function to select the proper tuple element:

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T> struct Cache 
{ 
    std::vector<T> x; 
    void add(T const& y) { x.push_back(y); }
};

template<class T1, class T2, class T3>
struct test
{
    test() : _caches(std::make_tuple(std::make_shared<Cache<T1>>(), 
        std::make_shared<Cache<T2>>(), std::make_shared<Cache<T3>>())) {}
    std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<Cache<T1>>, std::shared_ptr<Cache<T2>>, 
        std::shared_ptr<Cache<T3>>> _caches;
    template<class T>
    void add_item(T const& v)
    {
        std::get<std::shared_ptr<Cache<T>>>(_caches)->add(v);
    }
};

int main()
{
    test<int, float, double> a;
    a.add_item(1);
    std::cout << std::get<std::shared_ptr<Cache<int>>>(a._caches)->x.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `get<T>` does not compile if the tuple contains more than one item of type `T` so this solution requires `T1`, `T2` and `T3` to be distinct.